# Parse Error When Creating Form on Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, parsing

I'm creating a form on Symfony and I'm getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\wamp\www\estore\src\Estore\AdminBundle\Controller\AdminController.php on line 39.

Line 39 is:

```
->add('category', TextType::class)
```

Complete code:

```
namespace Estore\AdminBundle\Controller;
use Estore\AdminBundle\Entity\Categories;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/index")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new Response("Testing Routing on Admin Bundle to go to sleep");
    }


    /**
     * @Route("/admin/createcategories")
     */
    public function createCategoriesAction(Request $request)
    {

        $categories = new Categories();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($categories)
                     ->add('category', TextType::class)
                     ->add('description', TextType::class)
                     ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Category'))
                     ->getForm();
        return $thi->render('EstoreAdminBundle:Default:create_category.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Here some part of the Stack Trace information:

```
Stack Trace

in src\Estore\AdminBundle\Controller\AdminController.php at line 39  -
    $categories = new Categories(); 
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($categories) 
                 ->add('category', TextType::class) 
                 ->add('description', TextType::class) 
                 ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Category')) 
                 ->getForm(); 

          at Composer\Autoload\includeFile () 
          in vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php at line 301   

          at ClassLoader ->loadClass () 
          at ReflectionClass ->__construct () 
          in vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\AnnotationDirectoryLoader.php at line 52  

          at AnnotationDirectoryLoader ->load ()
```

I'm working with a git repository which is checked out from two computers. In one of them I don't have that issue. The difference between them is the computer with above error has PHP version 5.4.26 running on wamp. Symfony version 2.8.4-DEV - app/dev/debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is due to the php version

Using class as a name of a constant is available in PHP 5.5 only.

To get the class name you shouldreplace `TextType::class` with `get_class(new TextType)` or just `->add('category', 'text')`.

Answer (score 0):

::class is only supported from PHP 5.5 onwards.

Here's a quote from the Symfony Upgrade md file, until you upgrade to Symfony 3 or you upgrade php to 5.5, please use 'text' instead of the FQCN implementation.

> Type names were deprecated and will be removed in Symfony 3.0. Instead of referencing types by name, you should reference them by their fully-qualified class name (FQCN) instead. With PHP 5.5 or later, you can use the "class" constant for that:

This will fix your issue:

```
->add('category', 'text')
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct about needed php >= 5.5 for the `::class` to work. In contrast to them, I prefer to use

```
->add('category', 'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType')
```

this way the FQCN is already present. When you upgrade to php >=5.5 and/or Symfony 3.0, this will continue to work and won't require update.

Answer (score 0):

> return
>   $thi->render('EstoreAdminBundle:Default:create_category.html.twig',
>   array(
>               'form' => $form->createView(),
>           ));

```
$this->render
```